# Mondrian: Slicer axis ignored in query against a VirtualCube

Tags: mondrian

I created a `VirtualCube`, combining two other Cubes in my schema.
However, it seems that the slicer axis on queries made against this `VirtualCube` is being ignored.

This query returns the expected results:

```
SELECT
  NON EMPTY {
    [Measures].[FOB],
    [Measures].[CIF]
  } ON 0,
  NON EMPTY [Date].[Year].Members ON 1
FROM [exports_and_imports]
```

This one returns the same results as the previous one, which is incorrect:

```
SELECT
  NON EMPTY {
    [Measures].[FOB],
    [Measures].[CIF]
  } ON 0,
  NON EMPTY [Date].[Year].members ON 1
FROM [exports_and_imports]
WHERE (
        [Geography].[Washington]
      )
```

However, a slicer applied to the `Date` dimension *does* work:

```
  SELECT 
  NON EMPTY { 
    [Measures].[FOB], 
    [Measures].[CIF] 
  } ON 0 
FROM [exports_and_imports] 
WHERE ( 
        [Date].[Year].&[2005]:date.year.&[2014] 
      )
```

Edited version of my schema:

```
<Schema name="datachile">
  <Dimension name="Date" type="TimeDimension">...</Dimension>

  <Dimension name="Geography">...</Dimension>

  <Dimension name="Country">...</Dimension>

  <Dimension name=“HS”>...</Dimension>

  <Cube name="exports">
    <DimensionUsage name="Date" source="Date" foreignKey="date_id" />
    <DimensionUsage name="Destination Country" source="Country" foreignKey="country_dest_id" />
    <DimensionUsage name="Export Geography" source="Geography" foreignKey="exporter_comuna_id" />
    <DimensionUsage name="Export HS" source="HS" foreignKey="hs_level3" />

    <Measure name="FOB US" column="fob_us" aggregator="sum" />
  </Cube>

  <Cube name="imports">
    <DimensionUsage name="Date" source="Date" foreignKey="date_id" />
    <DimensionUsage name="Origin Country" source="Country" foreignKey="country_origin_id" />
    <DimensionUsage name="Import Geography" source="Geography" foreignKey="importer_comuna_id" />
    <DimensionUsage name="Import HS" source="HS" foreignKey="hs_6digits" />

    <Measure name="CIF US" column="cif_us" aggregator="sum" />
  </Cube>


  <VirtualCube name="exports_and_imports">
    <CubeUsages>
      <CubeUsage cubeName="exports" ignoreUnrelatedDimensions="true" />
      <CubeUsage cubeName="imports" ignoreUnrelatedDimensions="true" />
    </CubeUsages>

    <VirtualCubeDimension name="Date" />
    <VirtualCubeDimension name="Geography" />
    <VirtualCubeDimension name="HS" />

    <VirtualCubeMeasure cubeName="exports" name="[Measures].[FOB US]" />
    <VirtualCubeMeasure cubeName="imports" name="[Measures].[CIF US]"  />

    <CalculatedMember name="FOB" dimension="Measures">
      <Formula>ValidMeasure([Measures].[FOB US])</Formula>
    </CalculatedMember>

    <CalculatedMember name="CIF" dimension="Measures">
      <Formula>ValidMeasure([Measures].[CIF US])</Formula>
    </CalculatedMember>
  </VirtualCube>
</Schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a dimension called "Geography" in any of your cubes. There's one called "Import Geography" and another one called "Export Geography". Your virtual cube is trying to use the Geography dimension, which neither cube has, but as the hierarchy is defined with `hasAll="true"`, then the dimension defaults to the allMember in both cubes.

You need to define both Export and Import geography dimensions in your virtual cube and your slicer has to be

```
Union( [Import Geography].[Washington] * [Export Geography].[All], [Import Geography].[All] * [Export Geography].[Washington] )
```

(if what you're after is something like "show me total value in OR out of Washington).